# Local variable 'line' value is not used?

Tags: python, pycharm

When this script is used without the 'def main():' then the error doesn't appear but when it is inside this function the error seems to appear.

I have had a look into what I could find online regarding this issue but none of them can directly relate.

Sorry had to fix the code

```
def main():
    count = sum(1 for line in open('text.txt'))
```

Comment: There are maybe 3 different things wrong with that code snippet, and the message in your question title doesn't match any of them

Comment: How about now??

Comment: No, you still have unbalanced parentheses, `line` is not defined and `1 sum` is invalid

Comment: Your code has at least 2 syntax errors. You can safely ignore any and all PyCharm warnings until those are fixed.

Comment: This is python, anyways I had to fix my mistakes. This is what I should have typed.

Comment: You never use`line`. Try `sum(1 for _ in open('text.txt'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this isn't an error, it's a warning. You can ignore it if you want to, but personally I also like removing warnings.

The conventional way to signal to both readers and tools that a variable is intentionally unused is to name it `_` (a single underscore), e.g.

```
def main():
    count = sum(1 for _ in open('text.txt'))
```

In PyCharm, prefixing with an underscore (e.g. `_line`) also works if you want readers to know what the ignored variable is.